# Live Agent Reporting

Tags: liveagent

We have used Auto chat invite buttons on our web pages to allow customers to chat with our Agents. However we have not been able to report on the below 2 things in SFDC Live Agent -

1. Is there a way to track the number of auto chat invites rejected by customers on a web page ?
2. Is there a way to find out the URL of the web page from where the chat was initiated ?

Thanks

Comment: I am looking to report on the # invitations presented to the customer and subsequently # acceptance or # rejection.
Were you able to solve that problem?